# attribute is marked non-null but is null in Junit Test

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have an object like this

```html
   

 @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public class ChartDataSearchCondition {
      @NotNull
      @NotEmpty
      @Pattern(regexp = Constants.REGEX_CHART_CONDITION_DATE)
      private String startDate;
      @NotNull
      @NotEmpty
      @Pattern(regexp = Constants.REGEX_CHART_CONDITION_DATE)
      private String endDate;
      @NotNull @NotEmpty private List<String> columns;
    }
```

And here is my Unit Test

```html
   
  public ChartDataSearchCondition createChartRequest(
      String startDate, String endDate, List<String> columnList) {
    ChartDataSearchCondition chartDataSearchCondition = new ChartDataSearchCondition();
    chartDataSearchCondition.setColumns(columnList);
    chartDataSearchCondition.setStartDate(startDate);
    chartDataSearchCondition.setEndDate(endDate);
    return chartDataSearchCondition;
  }
  
 @Test()
  public void visualize_searchConditionWithEndDateIsNull() {
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    columns.add("col2");
    ChartDataSearchCondition chartDataSearchCondition =
        createChartRequest("2021-06-01 19:00:00.000+0700", null, columns);
    try {
      controller.getTimeseriesSampling(cluster, database, container, chartDataSearchCondition);
      Assert.fail();
    } catch (CommonException e) {
      assertThat(e.getCode(), is(ErrorCode.CHART_REQUEST_INVALID.getErrorCode()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Assert.fail();
    }
  }
```

But when i run my UnitTest, there is an error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: endDate is marked non-null but is null

What should i do to fix this problem ? Thank you very much

Comment: You excplicitly set `null` to `endDate`. The second parameter is enDate in this: `createChartRequest("2021-06-01 19:00:00.000+0700", null, columns);` But the field is marked as `@NotNull`.

Comment: I knew it, but my purpose is writing an unit test when endDate is Null

Comment: Then it is not a problem. So it doesn't have to fix as your asked, it had to be handled in tests.

Answer (score 0):

You passed a null value to `createChartRequest` at the `endDate` field at -

`ChartDataSearchCondition chartDataSearchCondition = createChartRequest("2021-06-01 19:00:00.000+0700", "Add a timestamp value here", columns);`